# Как создать систему регистрации?

Tags: apache, php, mysql

Как создать систему регистрации, вход и выход на локальном сервере. Необходимо создать на localhost.

Comment: Создавайте =) Возьмите какую-нибудь джумлу/вордпресс и не парьтесь, судя по постановке вопроса советы вам не нужны и не помогут.

Comment: Я вопрос, наверное, не правильно сформулировал, хотя спасибо)))

Comment: Подумать головой как это сделано на других ресурсах и написать.

Answer (score 1):

[Система регистрации](http://irbis-team.com/15/7). Хотя, возможно, сложновато вам для понимания будет.